# gRPC service not accessible from Traefik

Tags: grpc, traefik

I'm trying to route traffic for my gRPC service with Traefik. My Traefik configuration:

```
accessLog: 
  filePath: "/var/logs/access.log"

api:
  dashboard: true
  insecure: true

metrics:
  prometheus: {}

providers:
  nomad: 
    endpoint:
      address: http://host.docker.internal:4646

entryPoints:
  web:
    http2: 
      maxConcurrentStreams: 250
    address: ":80"
  grpc:
    http2: 
      maxConcurrentStreams: 250
    address: ":81"
```

When I spin up the container of my gRPC service, it is registered to Traefik, with h2c protocol:
[image: gRPC service]

When I send the gRPC request from Postman directly to the allocated node (127.0.0.1:29165), the request works:

[image: Postman request directly to container]

But if I want to send the request to the host, specified in rules (grpc.localhost), I get an error:
[image: gRPC error]

I tried changing entryPoint ports, and also disabling host header forwarding, but the problem persists.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.